# Error : SubQuery returns more than one records

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am trying to execute a query to fetch all students that belongs to a specific hostel,with hostel id, on SqlServer but facing the error *`Subquery returned more than 1 value.`* query is :

```
select * from students 
where StudentID=(select studentID from Student_To_Hostel where hostelID=2)
```

How to fix it ???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Method 1:**

You need to use **[JOIN](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/joins.php)** here

Try like this

```
SELECT S.* 
From Students S Inner JOIN Student_To_Hostel SH ON
              SH.StudentID =S.StudentID
WHERE SH.hostelID=2
```

**Method2:**

You can use **[IN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx)** Clause

```
SELECT * 
FROM students 
where StudentID IN (
                    SELECT studentID FROM Student_To_Hostel where hostelID=2
                   )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the '=' sign in the outer query with 'in'.

```
   select * from students 
   where StudentID in (select studentID from Student_To_Hostel where hostelID=2)
```

Hope it Helps

Vishad

Answer (score 0):

this is another way to do

```
select * from students 
where EXISTS (select studentID from Student_To_Hostel where hostelID=2)
```